# How do i display billing address for each product that has been successfully delivered to a customer/user

Tags: python, django

I was able to create a billing address using form, now i want to display the billing address in the customer's account (Order product). so when the customers want to check the information of all the product they have ordered, i want them to also see the billing address for each of the product, for example if they also uses a different billing addresses. I was able to get the address displayed on template, but it address gets duplicated on template, instead of displaying only the address for each product ordered.

[image]

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey('BillingAddress', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    payment = models.ForeignKey('Payment', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class BillingAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apartment_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField(multiple=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

def orders(request):
    order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, ordered=True)
    billing_address = BillingAddress.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)

    context = {
        'order': order,
        'billing_address_item': order_billing_address,
    }
    return render(request, 'orders.html', context)

{% for address in billing_address %}
Country: {{ address.street_address|capfirst }}
{% endfor %}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a separate query for billing address, fetch it from the order instance:

```
def orders(request):
    orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, ordered=True)

    context = {
        'orders': orders,
    }
    return render(request, 'orders.html', context)
```

orders.html:

```
{% for order in orders %}
    {{ order.billing_address.street_address }}
    {{ order.billing_address.country }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that the street address is duplicated for every order product, instead of for each. You can look at the image I uploaded under the Address Book.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it correctly by following your comment. I just needed to pass image instance also, and also I changed the styling of my template. Thanks very much.

Comment: sorry i have just one problem now, the code works and all products displayed on template. But the problem now is that the products gets duplicated on the template, instead of two product on order, it duplicated to four product, double for each. How do i make it display only a single product added to order template? I tried .distinct() and this does not work for me.